# jQuery GET request data encoding incorrect

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I query ASP.NET MVC WebAPI method using jQuery. On the server I receive value with incorrect encoding when I send russian chars.

On the server URL looks like that: http://example.com:8080/api/enums?term=��

� - instead of russian characters.

Here is jQuery ajax request code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/enums",
    data: "term=" + (options.term || ""),
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    success: callback,
});
```

I've put **contentType** parameter but no effect. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly of me. Here is correct jQuery code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/enums",
    data: {
       term: options.term || ""
    }
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    success: callback,
});
```